# Is there a difference in disenchanting strong items vs. weak ones?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disenchanting diminished return](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35641/disenchanting-diminished-return)

[This answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/40910/) states that the strength of the enchantment doesn't matter when disenchanting items to learn new enchantments.

Am I reading that right? If I have novice robes with 50% faster regen and disenchant it and my enchantment skill is at 5/5, when I enchant that item will it be the same result as disenchanting master robes with 150% faster regen? Because if you do the math, 5/5 enchanting will give you 100% better enchantment.

Therefore wouldn't it be better to disenchant more powerful items than weaker ones?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disenchanting diminished return](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35641/disenchanting-diminished-return). See also: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/41258/is-there-a-way-to-get-rid-of-the-old-enchant

Answer (score 5):

No. There is no difference.

When you disenchant an item you simply learn the "base enchant".

The strength of the enchant you apply to a weapon is a combination of the soul gem, your enchanting skill, your enchanting perks, and other enchanting modifiers (like armor or potions).  As seen [here](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Enchanting_Effects):

```
net magnitude = base magnitude * soul multiplier * skill multiplier 
                * (1 + Enchanter perk) * (1 + specific perk modifier)
```

That is, if you disenchant a novice level '+1 Health' Hide Helmet or a master level '+30 Health' Daedric Armor, you learn the same base enchant.